# How to take a boolean value from another class?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I have an UDP service which tell us if a number is 'capicua' or not. I have a Server Class with a boolean that set its value when is or when isnt. When i call from the class Client to tell me the boolean value i cannot take even with getter,setters or returning the actual booelan value, what do you think about?

```
//CLIENT CLASS
//TIPICO INFINITY LOOP
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero de "
                    + "al menos 2 cifras para ver si son capicúas. ");

            //METEMOS EN OUT ALL CONTENT 
            out =intToByteArray(Integer.parseInt(introducirDatos("Numero : "))) ;
            //ESCAPE
            if(byteArrayToInt(out)== 0) {
                System.out.println("Cerramos conexión...");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enviando " + out.length + " bytes al servidor");
            envio = new DatagramPacket(out, out.length, IPServer, port );
            socket.send(envio);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
            recibo = new DatagramPacket(in, in.length);
            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");
            socket.receive(recibo);

            IPOrigin = recibo.getAddress();
            int originPort = recibo.getPort();
            System.out.println("Procedente de: " + IPOrigin + ":" + originPort);

            boolean capicua = Servidor.isCapicua();
            System.out.println(capicua);



        }
        socket.close();
```

```
class Servidor{
static boolean capicua = true;

while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");

            // CONSTUIMOS NUESTRO DATAGRAMPACKET CON LOS DATOS DEL ARRAY DE BYTES
            recibo = new DatagramPacket(in, in.length);
            // RELLENAMOS EL SOCKET CON ALL CONTENT FROM RECIBO
            socket.receive(recibo);
            // ALMACENAMOS EN 'NUMERO' ALL CONTENT
            numero = new Integer(Cliente.byteArrayToInt(recibo.getData()));

            IPOrigin = recibo.getAddress();
            int port = recibo.getPort();
            System.out.println("Origen: " + IPOrigin + ":" + port);
            System.out.println("Mensaje recibido: " + numero);
            // VISUALIZMOS DATOS
            visualizar(recibo, socket);

            // AQUI ES DONDE TOCAMOS LA INFO RECIBIDA PARA DEVOLVER LA INFO ADULTERADA
            String answr = Integer.toString(capicuar(numero));

            if (numero == capicuar(numero)) {
                capicua = false;
            }
            System.out.println(capicua);

            // METEMOS LA INFO MODIFICADA EN DGP PARA ENVIAR
            // byte[] respuesta = Cliente.intToByteArray(answr);
            out = answr.getBytes();
            // PREPARAMOS EL ENVIO
            envio = new DatagramPacket(out, out.length, IPOrigin, port);
            // ENVIAMOS Y VUELTA A EMPEZAR

            socket.send(envio);
}
public static boolean isCapicua() {
        return capicua;
    }

    public static void setCapicua(boolean capicua) {
        Servidor.capicua = capicua;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a singleton class as follows (You can rename your singleton class to any other name you wish.)

```
public class SharedValues{

     private static SharedValues sharedValues = new SharedValues();
     //will always return the same instance of this class
     public static SharedValues getInstance() {
        return sharedValues;
     }

     private boolean capicua;

     public void setCapicua(boolean capicua)
     {
         this.capicua = capicua;
     }

     public boolean getCapicua()
     {
        return this.capicua;
     }
}
```

Then in class Servidor and class Client, do this:

```
class Servidor {
    SharedValues sharedValues = SharedValues.getInstance();

    //make sure this while loop code is in a function
    while(true)
    {
        if (numero == capicuar(numero)) {
            sharedValues.setCapicua(false);

        }
    }
}


class Client {
    SharedValues sharedValues = SharedValues.getInstance();

    //make sure this while loop code is in a function
    while(true)
    {
        boolean capicua = sharedValues.getCapicua();
        System.out.println(capicua);
    }
}
```

To simply explain it, a singleton class is a class that can only have one instance. Thus, the same instance of SharedValues class will be accessed by both class Servidor and class Client. If you thus set the value in Servidor as *setCapicua(false)*, then in class Client you will get it as false if you call *getCapicua()*. You must however, realize that in both Client and Servidor, the instantiation is `SharedValues sharedValues = SharedValues.getInstance();` Please **DO NOT** use `SharedValues sharedValues = new SharedValues();` This will give a new instance of class SharedValues and will not serve the purpose.

Comment: Really appreciate it. That was 100% exactness. I was looking for a variable outside the program able to send 0/1 when something happens. Learned a lot with this trick, really thank you!!

Comment: You are very much welcome. You can tick the answer as the accepted one. Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.

Comment: sorry i was out for a long time!! it will be accepted as the right one